# How do I reduce the amount of debugging messages from javax.net.debug=ssl?

Tags: java, ssl

When I don't use debugging I get a

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

As to why I enabled

javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake

to figure out what is going wrong.

However, while that is enabled, instead I get

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Every time... I figured it's most likely due to the sheer amount of time it takes to write the debugging log... So, how do I reduce the amount so I can get to debugging the handshake_failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flag is most likely right. I typically use either -Djavax.net.debug=all or -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose

You'll still get the socket closure, but the root cause is most likely something else.
See https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

Complete details on debugging SSL/TLS are available in the [JSSE Reference Guide Debugging section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug).

Consider applying the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strengh jurisdiction policy files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) for your Java version in case the handshake specifies stronger versions of the algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using only `javax.net.debug=ssl`? It could be enough to understand what is going on, other than this, it's weird, i don't remember the `handshake` option adding all those additional messages.

Comment: I suppose you are logging something else too, how about disabling everything else and just leave the ssl messages?